# select multiple columnns, group by one column, involves clob

Tags: sql, database, oracle, types

I want to select multiple columns from 3 tables, and group by self_object_id. One of the columns(gene_info) is of the CLOB type.

I tried using max() for each column except self_object_id, but I couldn't because this function would not for for the CLOB datatype. How do I work around?

```
SELECT gene_info, pi.id, race, id_card_no, sdg.create_datetime
FROM person_info pi, sample_info si, sample_dna_gene sdg
WHERE pi.id = si.self_object_id
AND si.self_object_id = sdg.sample_id
AND si.self_object_id IN ('34B00F424CFE4DA389A7F7914D54AA62','8EF79471D9A3481590BD4CA6FC09231E','43E85B5BC34  94EA6B71D3D289A3A8AF0')
GROUP BY self_object_id
```

Comment: Why are you using commas in the `FROM` clause instead of proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax?  Why haven't you qualified all column names, so other people know where the columns are coming from.

Comment: because I don't know how to properly use join when I have 3 tables. I know how to use it when i'm only joining 2. where seems most straight forward and gives me the right result.

Comment: . . (1) It is not very hard to add a `JOIN` after the second table; there are many examples around.  (2) I can't follow the query logic because I don't know what tables the columns are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot `GROUP BY` a `CLOB`. You just can't. You'll have to find some other way of doing that. If your `CLOBs` are fairly short, under 4000 characters, you can convert them to `VARCHAR2s` and group them that way. Personally, I dislike Oracle-style `JOINs`, but they are valid.

Actually, wait. You have no aggregation in this query, so you don't need any sort of `GROUP BY` clause. Are you trying to remove duplicates? `DISTINCT` is the way to do that.

```
select distinct
       dbms_lob.substr( gene_info, 4000 ) as gene_info, 
       pi.id, race, id_card_no, sdg.create_datetime
  from person_info pi, 
       sample_info si on si.self_object_id = pi.id, 
       sample_dna_gene sdg on sdg.sample_id = si.self_object_id
 where si.self_object_id in ( ... )
```

Comment: Thanks I got it to work with to_char(), and adding max() for all but the column I want to use group by for.

Comment: also I don't think distinct would work how I wanted here. it would return unique combinations rather than the specific column